# dynamically change label text QML

Tags: qt, qml, blackberry-10

This is the silliest thing to do in any language but I'm stuck on how to do it in QML.

How to change the text value of a Label in QML? What am I missing..

My code is the following:

```
Container {
  objectName: "formContainer"
  id: formContainer

  property alias text1: labelTest.text

  onCreationCompleted: {
      Qt.labelTest = labelTest;
      Qt.text1 = formContainer.text1;
  }

  Label {
      id: labelTest
      text: "test"
  }

  TextField {
      id: textFieldPass
      onFocusedChanged: {
             if (focused) {
                     Qt.myFunction();
             }
      }
   }

    function myFunction(){
       //Enter successfuly to the function
       console.log("Qt.labelTest.text:" + Qt.labelTest.text);  //Output: undefined
       Qt.labelTest.text = "Y U NO change!";  //Does nothing
       Qt.text1 = "Y U NO change!";           //Does nothing  
    }
 }
```

I'm not sure why is not working. Even with an alias property the text refuses to change.
I will appreciate any help.

Thanks and regards.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to access alias using the control's id.aliasname. & make myFunction global by declaring it in its root (i.e. Page in this case), if it is being used in multiple slots like this:

```
Page {
function myFunction() {
    formContainer.text1 = "Y U NO change!";
}
Container {
    id: formContainer
    property alias text1: labelTest.text
    Label {
        id: labelTest
        text: "test"
    }
    TextField {
        id: textFieldPass
        onFocusedChanged: {
            if (focused) {
                myFunction();
            }
        }
     }
  }
}
```

or if it is being used only for TextField control, you can make it local for it like this:

```
Page {
Container {
    id: formContainer
    property alias text1: labelTest.text
    Label {
        id: labelTest
        text: "test"
    }
    TextField {
        id: textFieldPass
        onFocusedChanged: {
            if (focused) {
                myFunction();
            }
        }
        function myFunction() {
            formContainer.text1 = "Y U NO change!";
        }
    }
}
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

You do not have to use the Qt.'something' to change the properties of the QML objects. The way to change the properties is by 'objectId'.'property' = "value";. So try this:

```
Container {
  objectName: "formContainer"
  id: formContainer

  Label {
    id: labelTest
    text: "test"
  }

  TextField {
    id: textFieldPass
    onFocusedChanged: {
      if (focused) {
        myFunction();
      }
    }
  }

  function myFunction(){
   //Enter successfuly to the function
   console.log("labelTest.text:" + labelTest.text);
   labelTest.text = "Y U NO change!";  //Does nothing
  }
}
```